# Allow applications to access online meetings on behalf of a user

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams

The functions described in the following article do not exist in any of the powershell packages that I can find for Teams/Skype.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy
Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy

Looking for a way to Allow applications to access online meetings on behalf of a user - anyone have suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be any part of existing package of your powershell installation. You need an administrator or owner level user of your subscription to import it.

Have your admin user follow the below steps:

1. Open Powershell in admin mode
2. type Install-Module MicrosoftTeams
3. type Y
4. type Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope CurrentUser
5. type
   Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
   $sfbSession = New-CsOnlineSession
   Import-PSSession $sfbSession

After that, your admin person can run the New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy and Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy for you.